# onclick excecutes does not work, only when creating DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML and javascript. 
I can create the buttons without any problem, but the onclick function does not work when clicking the button. It does not do anything.

If I put the method without the ' it excecutes when generating the form, one after the other generating 3 dialogs

```js
function makeUL(array) {
  var list = document.createElement('ul');

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    /*
    btn.onClick = function () {
        buttonClicked(array[i]);
    };*/

    var t = document.createTextNode(array[i]); // Create a text node
    btn.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <button>
    btn.type = "button"
    btn.onClick = 'buttonClicked()';
    list.appendChild(btn); // Append <button> to <body>
    var nextLine = document.createElement("td");
    list.appendChild(nextLine);
  }
  return list;
}
/*
function buttonClicked(buttonName){
    alert(buttonName);
}*/
function buttonClicked() {
  alert("algo");
}

self.onInit = function() {
  var boton = [];
  for (var g = 0; g < self.ctx.settings.Botones.length; g++) {
    boton[0] = self.ctx.settings.Botones[g].btnId;
    boton[1] = self.ctx.settings.Botones[g].method;
    boton[2] = self.ctx.settings.Botones[g].params;
    document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(makeUL(boton));
  }


  self.ctx.$scope.sendCommand = function() {
    var timeout = self.ctx.settings.requestTimeout;
    var rpcMethod = self.ctx.settings.method;
    var rpcParams = self.ctx.settings.params;

    var commandPromise;
    commandPromise = self.ctx.controlApi.sendTwoWayCommand(rpcMethod, rpcParams, timeout);
    commandPromise.then(
      function success(response) {
        //alert("Comando recibido exitosamente\n Respuesta:" + angular.toJson(response));
        alert("Comando recibido exitosamente");
      },
      function fail(rejection) {
        alert("ERROR AL ENVIAR COMANDO");
      }
    );
  };
};
```

```html
<form name="rpcForm">
  <md-content class="md-padding" layout="column">
    <div id="myList"></div>
  </md-content>
</form>
```

Comment: are you using angular? what is this  `md-content`

Comment: You've to assign `btn.onClick` a function, not a string. So use the function-name without `''`. And also don't use the parentheses `()` after function-name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
btn.onClick = 'buttonClicked()';
```

It looks like you were trying to assign to the `onclick` *attribute* of the HTML, in which case the proper syntax would be

```
btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'buttonClicked()');
```

But since you already have a reference to the element, there's no need to resort to attributes; inline handlers are pretty bad practice anyway. Change to:

```
btn.onclick = buttonClicked;
```

(note the lower-case `c` in `onclick`), or

```
btn.addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);
```

Also, you might consider simply assigning to the button's `textContent` rather than creating a text node explicitly, it's a bit easier to read and write: change

```
var t = document.createTextNode(array[i]); // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <button>
```

to

```
btn.textContent = array[i];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, btn.onclick = buttonClicked worked, but since I have several buttons, I need to pass the buttons name via parameter to the function, how can I do that? I was doing the following, buttonClicked(array[i]) which created the alert with the correct name when the form was created, but did not listen to the click

Comment: Make another function - change to `btn.onclick = () => buttonClicked(array[i]);` (or use `.bind` to assign the argument in advance)

Comment: .bind worked correctly. I created another attribute (btn.id = array[i]), changed to btn.onclick = buttonClicked.bind(button) and added in the buttonClicked() function alert(this.id). Thanks for your help